# Trouble combining checkboxes with this find function

Tags: jquery, find, show-hide

I'm having trouble getting this `find` function to work properly with checkboxes. I wasn't able to select any checkboxes and was therefore told to remove the statement `return false;` I'm not sure if that's the cause or not, but the statement `if (attrColor == 'All'){...}` is no longer working.

How can I modify this function so that it will work with checkboxes, including showing all if that's selected?

I've posted a fiddle with a simple example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/92/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected = [];
    $('#attributes-Colors *').click(function () {
        var attrColor = $(this).data('color');
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(attrColor),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected.push(attrColor);
        }
        if (attrColor == 'All') {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } else {
        $("#content").find("*").hide();
        $.each(selected, function(index,item) {
            $('#content').find('[data-color *="' + item + '"]').show();
        });
        }
        // Removed this to allow checkboxes to accept input
        //return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly what you want ?

Comment: @DevangRathod - When the user clicks on "All Colors" It should show all the items, but that statement isn't working now.

Comment: There seem to be lots of problems with your code. First, you're binding to all elements in the DIV, not just the checkboxes. Second, you don't prevent event bubbling, so the handler runs 3 times when you click on a checkbox. Third, you don't distinguish between checking and unchecking the box when you test `attrColor == 'All'`.

Comment: @Barmar - Would you mind showing me how to correct those issues? Another SO member reworked my original function to allow filtering by more than one value, and the code is a bit more advanced than I am ;-)

Comment: What was wrong with the answer in your earlier question?

Comment: @Barmar - I needed to add the checkboxes (it didn't have any input elements in the <li> previously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the checkboxes only, and not all the elements like the asterix selector does, and use the "change" event for checkboxes.

Then get all the li elements in the variable `lis`, and hide all of them at the same time.

Map all the checked checkboxes colors into an array with `$.map`.

`isAll` checks that array for the value "All" to see if that checkbox is checked, if it is, or if no checkboxes are checked, i.e. the length is null, show all `li's`, otherwise iterate over the colors from the checked checkboxes with `$.each`, and show any of the lis matching the selected colors.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#attributes-Colors input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
        var lis = $('#content li').hide(),
            check = $.map($('#attributes-Colors input[type="checkbox"]'), function (el,i) {
                if (el.checked) return $(el).data('color');
            }),
            isAll = $.inArray('All', check) != -1;

        if (check.length && !isAll) {
            $.each(check, function(i,color) {
                lis.filter(function() {
                    return $(this).data('color').indexOf(color) != -1
                }).show();
            });
        } else {
            lis.show();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WZpMh/107/)

Comment: Thank you :-D Would it be possible for you to include some comments explaining the code because there are several new things that I'm not familiar with

Comment: That helped a lot :-D I'm also a little confused by the variables 'el' and 'i', which aren't defined in the usual manner